# Why is received websocket data coming out as a buffer?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I'm trying to do a very basic websocket, but i dont understand why I'm not getting a string back.

I'm using the `ws` module from npm for the server. https://github.com/websockets/ws

client:

```
    let socket = new WebSocket('wss://upload.lospec.com');

    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        socket.send('test');
    });
```

server:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on("connection", function (ws) {
    ws.on("message", function (asdfasdf) {
        console.log("got new id from client",asdfasdf);
    });
```

server result:

```
got new id from client <Buffer 74 65 73 74>
```

Trying to follow the examples on the docs, as well as this tutorial: https://ably.com/blog/web-app-websockets-nodejs

But it's not coming out like a string like both places promise.

Why isn't this coming out as a string?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You probably use a different version of `ws` than the tutorial does. It seems like the tutorial uses a version older than v8, while you use a version of v8+.

From the [changelog for 8.0.0](https://github.com/websockets/ws/releases/tag/8.0.0):

> Text messages and close reasons are no longer decoded to strings. They are passed as `Buffer`s to the listeners of their respective events.
> The listeners of the `'message'` event now take a boolean argument specifying whether or not the message is binary ([`e173423`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/commit/e173423c180dc1e4e6ee8938d9e4376a7a8b9757)).
>
> Existing code can be migrated by decoding the buffer explicitly.
>
> ```js
> websocket.on('message', function message(data, isBinary) {
>   const message = isBinary ? data : data.toString();
>   // Continue as before.
> });
> ```
>
> ```js
> websocket.on('close', function close(code, data) {
>   const reason = data.toString();
>   // Continue as before.
> });
> ```

This also describes the solution.

Alternatively, you can downgrade to version 7.5.0 of `ws` to be on par with [what the tutorial uses](https://github.com/ably-labs/websockets-cursor-sharing/blob/5e052e7d3c13df6745a76bc6b976194f61bcbfca/api/package.json#L13):

```sh
npm i ws@7.5.0
```

In regards to the example "sending and receiving text data" in the library docs: I believe it's an oversight on their end that this example wasn't updated when v8 was released. You could open an issue on GitHub to let them know.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense (and does seem to work now).

Comment: Also I wonder if the %s part in the documentation examples is automatically forcing it to be converted to a string, which is why toString is not needed (and I suspect that JSON.stringify does that too, which I've seen a few times exclude toString)

Comment: Even then the example would be misleading, as is apparent from this very question.

Comment: Do you know of an official documentation for this outside of the github repository? I can't find anything on this or the react version of websockets.

Comment: What do you mean? The _official_ GitHub repo has the _official_ documentation (https://github.com/websockets/ws), why would it need another one?

Comment: @stackers Thanks for the edit suggestion but this is a citation from the changelog and therefore it doesn't make sense to change it. Also, the logic does seem correct - if it's binary, it cannot be properly converted to a string, so it should stay as buffer; otherwise it is converted to string.

Answer (score 0):

In Latest version one need to provide **%s** while printing the received message. Here is the simple code snippet from official page [npm websocket official page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#api-docs).

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use console.log(` ${data} `), it will not show <Buffer.
where as if you console.log(data), it will show <Buffer
e.g.

```
    ws.on('message',data=>{
        console.log(`user sended:${data}`)
    })
```

It's a bug or normal you can say.

alter method:

```
    ws.on('message',data=>{
        data=data.toString()
        console.log("user sended:",data)
    })
```

OR

```
    ws.on('message',data=>{
        console.log("user sended:",data.toString())
    })
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's simply because in one case you coerce it to a string by using it in a template literal and in the other case you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. I found the issue was because of version of `ws`.
So, I installed another version of `ws`.

Try this instead:

```
npm i ws@7.5.0
```

It worked in my case.